# Ubuntu FanControl settings using pwmconfig

Tags: dual-boot, 15.10, fan, fancontrol, lm-sensors

I am using Ubuntu 15 on Dell inspiron 7559 laptop.
I have dual booted Windows and Ubuntu.
When I use windows the fans work perfectly but when using Ubuntu they make too much noise and run at high speeds even when the laptop is very cool.

I read about how you can control fan speeds using lm-sensors and fancontrol and configure it using pwmconfig.
Is there a way I can figure out the settings that the fans work on when I am using Windows and then configure the same settings in Ubuntu.
If not, Is there any other solution to the problem.

I see "ACPI FAN" listed under device manager -> system devices.
Is there any change that I have to do in ubuntu configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Does the BIOS have an option to control the fan speed? If so use it and then the fan speed control will be independent of the operating system.

I have not used Windows since XP, but as far as I am aware the Windows operating system does not have fan speed control built in, so you are using a Windows application to control your fan speeds. This application is probably SpeedFan. Run it under Windows and record the settings.

Then under Ubuntu install, setup and run lm-sensors. Once sensors is reporting your fan speeds then install and run pwmconfig. Set it up to duplicate the settings you like from SpeedFan.